# Is the tensor product of two real numbers a real number?

Tags: tensor-products

I am on a physics course where they've introduced the tensor product as if it was something that I would have seen before, and they don't tell me any of its properties. However, I am trying to work them out on my own.

My question is: suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ functions. Does that mean that $f(x)\otimes g(x) 
$ is the real number obtained by $ f(x)\cdot g(x)$, where $\cdot$ is ordinary multiplication on the reals, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Isomorphic to a real number (pedantically speaking), but otherwise yes (I believe)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asserting. Are you asking whether, given two *arbitrary* real-valued *functions* $f$ and $g$ on $R^d$, the tensor product of them -- of the *functions* -- is itself a *function*, whose value at $x\in R^d$ is just the ordinary product of the values of $f$ and $g$ at $x$? This isn't quite right. The tensor product of two tensors (construed as **multilinear** maps) $f:R^m\to R$ and $g:R^n\to R$ is a new multilinear function $R^{m+n}\to R$ defined by $f\otimes g(x,y):=f(x)g(y)$ for $x$ in $R^m$ and $y$ in $R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

In general $f\otimes g$ is a **bilinear map** $\Bbb R^d\times\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R$ which is defined by $$f\otimes g(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$$ 
and in particular it can be evaluated at $(x,x)$.